# MongoDB: Is it possible to combine 2 requests into one?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

2 collections that I have:

`Users`:

```
{
_id: "user_unique_id_123",
email: "user@google.com" 
}
```

And `Products`:

```
{
_id: "unique_product_id",
name: "product name",
user: "user_unique_id_123"
}
```

As an input parameter, I receive an `email address` and I need to extract all `Products` associated with that `email address`.

The problem is that the **preferable** way just makes only `one` request to the MongoDB, not 2 separate requests:
to extract `user Id` by `email` and after extract `Products` by `user-id`.

So, could you please suggest, is it even possible to have only one call instead of 2?

Comment: Did you try using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#lookup-aggregation)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CoystaMlJcK)

```
db.Users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Products",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "user",
      "as": "userProducts"
    }
  }
])
```

```
{"$lookup":
{
 "from": "collection to join",
 "localField": "field from the input documents",
 "foreignField": "field from the documents of the from collection",
 "as": "output array field"
 }
```